# Methods of matching nodes and edges supported by Memgraph

Tags: memgraphdb

I am looking into the various techniques available for matching nodes and edges within graph databases, and am particularly interested in understanding the capabilities of Memgraph in this regard. Since there are multiple ways to match nodes and edges, I am curious to know what unique or standard methods are supported by Memgraph. Are there specific clauses or functionalities that Memgraph provides for this purpose? Any examples or references to the documentation would be highly appreciated. I couldn't find anything on Memgraph website or in their docs.

Comment: It would be helpful in the question to describe what you have tried so far, and why it worked or did not work for your purposes. As I understand it Memgraph supports openCypher which offers many ways to do pattern matching. Is that not proving adequate for your use case?

Comment: You are right. I should have included more info. I was reading paper Graph pattern matching: A brief survey of challenges and research directions (https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7724255) and I wanted to learn what Memgraph uses. This paper predates Memgraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memgraph supports something called Cyphermophism. The detailed explanation can be found under  [Graph pattern matching semantics](https://s3.amazonaws.com/artifacts.opencypher.org/website/ocim1/slides/cypher_implementers_day_2017_pattern_matching_semantics.pdf) from the First openCypher Implementers Meeting.

Disclaimer: I work at Memgraph.